# Как заполнить бинарное дерево N-глубины?

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Как заполнить бинарное дерево N-глубины?

Comment: Что значит заполнить? Обойти все элементы?

Comment: void printTree(struct node* node) {

    if (node == NULL) return;
    printTree(node->left);
    node->data = ...;//заполняем
    printTree(node->right);
}

Answer (score 2):

посмотрите
Абстракция данных и решение задач на C++. Стены и зеркала
Каррано Ф.М., Причард Дж.Дж.
там очень подробно эта тема рассмотрена